# How to get an Array inside of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a multidimensional array which is stored as `$_SESSION['basket']`, I have displayed the arrays stored in the `$_SESSION['basket']` using a foreach loop and now I am trying to retrieve a specific array stored in the `$_SESSION['basket']` when a user clicks to delete the item, for example, this is my `var_dump()`:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(11) "User2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["ProductId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "40"
    ["product"]=>
    string(10) "Levi Pants"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(11) "User2"
    ["ownerID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["ProductId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "17"
    ["product"]=>
    string(6) "Jumper"
  }
}
```

The foreach loop:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["basket"])) {
    if (count($_SESSION["basket"])>0) {
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo '<table class="table table-hover"><thead><tr>';
        echo '<th>Owner</th><th>Product</th><th>Price</th><th class="text-center">Action</th>    </tr>';
        echo '</thead><tbody>';
        foreach ($_SESSION["basket"] as $basket) {


            echo '<tr><td>' . $basket["username"]. '</td><td>' . $basket["product"]. '</td><td>' .$basket["price"]. '</td><td class="text-center"><a href="/removeproduct.php?ID='.$basket[2]. '"><button id="view" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></a></td></tr>';

    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

How would i retrieve the second array without specifying the array for example `$basket[2]`?

Comment: sory .... I figured wrong.

Comment: @BuseGönen Yes, but since I have a forreach loop how would I get the array for each item?

Comment: Show us your code/ foreach loop

Comment: foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $vall ){  print_r($vall); }

Comment: @KovachSullivan Now you have your answer :D

Comment: foreach ($_SESSION["basket"] as $key => $basket) {  .... <a href="/removeproduct.php?ID='.$key. '">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["basket"] as $basket) {
```

to

```
foreach ($_SESSION["basket"] as $key => $basket) {
```

And then you can add a if condition in your foreach loop like that:

```
if($key == 2)
    unset($_SESSION["basket"][$key]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect! I just wanted to unset the array which was clicked for deletion, so just unset($_SESSION["basket"][$key]); without the IF statement was good enough!

Comment: I have sent the ARRAY to the removeproduct.php by doing ?ID='.$key.' and this is the code in the remove product to check if the ID isset,

Comment: if (isset($_GET["ID"])) {

            unset($_SESSION["basket"][$_GET["ID"]]);
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Product removed from basket.</div>';

        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">You must select a product to remove from the basket.</div>';
        } but now for some reason it says "Product removed from basket" when i tamper with the URL, so if I leave the ID?= blank without any id